# What is the lowest model of Nexus line with guard in the tongue?

Tags: equipment, skating

The padding is some kind of foam, or sponge. You can squeeze it, every piece of it works independently, so lace make a line in it.

The guard is some kind of plastic. You cannot squeeze it, entire guard works as one piece, so lace has a surface of it.

The lowest models of Vapors line is X.70, and of Supremes One.7 (the thickness of the guard is different though). Lower models have only padding (foam).

**The question is** -- what is the lowest model of Nexus that comes with guard, not padding.

*Please don't quote official Bauer website, it is incorrect for Vapors for sure, so I would not like to rely on it for Nexus.*